# jQuery Waypoints fires on page load when images are display block

Tags: jquery-waypoints

Im using the jQuery waypoints plugin. This following is working fine except on page load the console message is fired before ive scrolled. This stops If I remove the display block being applied to the images, but I need this for my site to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/waypoints.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            img {
                max-width: 100%;
                display: block;
                margin: auto;
            }
            #img3 {
                opacity: 0.5;
            }

        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#img3').waypoint(function() {
                  console.log('Basic example callback triggered.');
                });
            });
        </script>
    <body>
        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image 1" id="img1">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="image 2" id="img2">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="image 3" id="img3">
        <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="image 4" id="img4">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your images do not have width/height until they start loading. You are instantiating the waypoint during the `domready` event, before your images start loading. At that time, because they do not have width/height, all your images live at the y coordinate of 0 on the page, and that's where the waypoint triggers. You can solve this at least two ways:

- Give your images a width+height in your HTML.
- Create the waypoint within a `$(window).load` handler, which will wait until all images are finished loading.

The reason this was not happening when the images are inline is that the 0x0 img element lives within the line-height text box of `body`, so the img lives some small number of pixels from the top instead of the exact top.