# Jquery Skill bar effect starts when you scroll to the section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want my skill bar effect starts when I scroll to that section for example im in my intro section when I scroll down to the skill section it will trigger the effect :) thank you so much!

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-centered">
           <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="95%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #131313;"><span>Photography</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #131313;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">95%</div>
</div>

 <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="85%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #131313;"><span>Videography</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #131313;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">85%</div>
</div>

 <div class="skillbar clearfix" data-percent="75%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #131313;"><span>Illustrator</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #131313;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">75%</div>
</div>

<script> 
jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
  jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
    width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
  },6000);
});

</script>
```

CSS:

```
.skillbar {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
    height:35px;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-transition:0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition:0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition:0.4s linear;
    -o-transition:0.4s linear;
    transition:0.4s linear;
    -webkit-transition-property:width, background-color;
    -moz-transition-property:width, background-color;
    -ms-transition-property:width, background-color;
    -o-transition-property:width, background-color;
    transition-property:width, background-color;
}

.skillbar-title {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#6adcfa;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3px;
    border-top-left-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}

.skillbar-title span {
    display:block;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding:0 20px;
    height:35px;
    line-height:35px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3px;
    border-top-left-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}

.skillbar-bar {
height:35px;
width:0px;
background:#6adcfa;
border-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
float: left;
}

.containers {
    min-height: 100%;
      height: 100vh;


}
.skill-bar-percent {
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:0;
    font-size:11px;
    height:35px;
    line-height:35px;
    color:#444;
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Show us some `html` too or try **[`animate.css`](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao updated it! thx :)

Comment: **[Check this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16327815/2065039)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the window `.scrollTop()` value against the vertical position `.offset().top` of the container div of the `.skillbar`. the latter div will enter the view when the window scroll position added to the value of the window height is just triggered larger than the top offset of the container div, or in other words, when:

```
jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > jQuery('#skills').offset().top
```

Then the `.animate()` function will be triggered.

** *Note* that I assigned the id `skills` to the `<div class="col-md-5 col-centered">`

check this out:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/81ngace8/1/)

```js
var skillsDiv = jQuery('#skills');

jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var winT = jQuery(window).scrollTop(),
    winH = jQuery(window).height(),
    skillsT = skillsDiv.offset().top;
  if (winT + winH > skillsT) {
    jQuery('.skillbar').each(function() {
      jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
        width: jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
      }, 6000);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:1200px;
}
#test{
  height:800px;
}
.skillbar {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
    height:35px;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-transition:0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition:0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition:0.4s linear;
    -o-transition:0.4s linear;
    transition:0.4s linear;
    -webkit-transition-property:width, background-color;
    -moz-transition-property:width, background-color;
    -ms-transition-property:width, background-color;
    -o-transition-property:width, background-color;
    transition-property:width, background-color;
}

.skillbar-title {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#6adcfa;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3px;
    border-top-left-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}

.skillbar-title span {
    display:block;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding:0 20px;
    height:35px;
    line-height:35px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3px;
    border-top-left-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}

.skillbar-bar {
height:35px;
width:0px;
background:#6adcfa;
border-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
float: left;
}

.containers {
    min-height: 100%;
      height: 100vh;


}
.skill-bar-percent {
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:0;
    font-size:11px;
    height:35px;
    line-height:35px;
    color:#444;
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!</div>
<div id="skills" class="col-md-5 col-centered">
           <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="95%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #131313;"><span>Photography</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #131313;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">95%</div>
</div>

 <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="85%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #131313;"><span>Videography</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #131313;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">85%</div>
</div>

 <div class="skillbar clearfix" data-percent="75%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #131313;"><span>Illustrator</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #131313;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">75%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You welcome @ElMucho, I'm glad it helped, enjoy coding;

Comment: So much better than most plugins out there. Thanks a lot