# addClass are added to all DIV's regardless of their position (viewport)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've searched a solution for my problem but I didn't find any answer for that.

here is the problem, I'm using animate.css for many DIVs but I want the animations take effect when the element -which has classes 'animated' and 'animation in animate.css'- is in viewport. My problem is that classes 'animated' and 'animation in animate.css' are added to all my DIV's whatever the position is.

**the script**

```
$(function() {
"use strict";
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    addClassToElementInViewport($('div.accueilText'), "slideInleft");
    addClassToElementInViewport($('div.ateHT'), "slideInLeft");
  });

  function addClassToElementInViewport(element, newClass) {
    if (isVisible(element)) {
      element.removeClass('hidden');
      element.addClass(newClass);
    }
  }

function isVisible($el) {
  var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var winBottom = winTop + $(window).height();
  var elTop = $el.offset().top;
  var elBottom = elTop + $el.height();
  return ((elBottom<= winBottom) && (elTop >= winTop));
}

});
```

**html code**

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center accueilText hidden animated">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">blablabla bla bla<br>bla<br>blabla bla  </div>
      </div>
      <hr>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><center><img class="img-responsive" src="Images/verin_hydroseb.png" alt="Hydroseb logo"></center></div>
      </div>
      </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="text-justify col-sm-5 ateHT hidden animated"> <br>bla bla blabllabla </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2 ateHI hidden animated"> <img class="img-responsive" src="Images/atelier_hydraulique.png" alt="HydroSeb Hydraulique"></div>

  </div>
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide :)

Comment: Then your viewport method may be incorrect. See my answer here and try the viewport method provided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955204/animate-skill-bars/42955954#42955954

Comment: You say your css isn't working, then don't post any css...

Comment: works fine here : http://codepen.io/NirBenya/pen/EWMxgE

Comment: yess i'm sorry for my explanation.
the problem is that i want them to be added when they are in the viewport.
but one the first class id added, my function add classes to my other DIVs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$('div.accueilText') this will find all divs with class accueilText

But i feel you may be looking for this.

First of all `on-screen visible area` is known as `Viewport`.

[image: image is took from OP and cleaned up in Photoshop]

> *(image is taken from OP. Cleared and edited in **Photoshop**)*

---

So all you need is to detect all elements in your `Viewport`.

This can be achieved using many plugins for jQuery, but I'll explain you on one example, which is called as `jQuery withinviewport`

Link to source and documentation on: [**[ withInViewport - Github ]**](https://github.com/patik/within-viewport)

---

## Step 1:

Download plugins and include `jQuery` framework and `withinviewport` plugin in your script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="withinViewport.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.withinviewport.js"></script>
```

.

## Step 2:

Initialise function on `scroll` event:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    //your code placeholder
});
```

.

## Step 3:

Use `withinviewport` selector to get all elements in you Viewport and by each element add class to corresponding list-item in your `#timeline` container:

```
$("#elements > div").withinviewport().each(function() {
   $('#timeline > li[view-id="'+$(this)[0].id+'"]').addClass('active');
});
```

## Step 4:

Put all together:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {

    //clear all active class
    $('#timeline > li').removeClass('active');

    //add active class to timeline
    $("#elements > div").withinviewport().each(function() {
         $('#timeline > li[view-id="'+$(this)[0].id+'"]').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

.

---

.

Also this plugin gives you opportunity to set top, bottom, left and right offset for view-port.

**See demo here**: http://patik.com/code/within-viewport/

Comment: Origionally posted as top answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498068/how-to-get-on-screen-visible-element-objects-in-jquery